# How to read json response of a node server from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I have an Angular frontend which takes id and password for a login form,then I POST this value to a node.js server and from this server I send a JSON object back to Angular.

All works fine except the reading of this object from Angular. I think I've done the right steps, but the console shows me "undefined" as if it does not recognize the format.

I'm new with node and this is just an example to try to catch the response from node.

---

#### My server-side JS (Node.js) :

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    console.log("sono nella post "+req.body.username);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.json({ack:'ok'});
});
app.listen(9080,function(){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:9080/');
});
```

#### My client-side JS (Angular) :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.check = function(data) {
        var id = data.form.id;
        var pwd = data.form.password;
        console.log("utente è "+id+",password è "+pwd);
        var msg = {username: id,password: pwd};
        $http({
            // without anything here, put * in app.post()
            url : 'http://localhost:9080/login',
            method : "POST",
            data : $.param(msg),
            responseType : "application/json",
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log("Server response "+response.ack);
        });
    };
});
```

When running this, the console shows me `Server response undefined`.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: First step should have been one of the following: add a debugger line to the callback and check the value of `response`, add a breakpoint and do the same, or console.log(response) directly. That likely would have solved the problem for you without you having to spend your time and our time here.

Comment: console.log will only get you so far. Open up chrome dev tools, put a breakpoint at the code you are having issues with and inspect the objects.

Edit: if you are intent on using console.log then console.log(JSON.stringify(response)); will give you much richer feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,I've solved using response.data.ack. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Angular `$http` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> - **config** – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.

So, if you try `response.data.ack`, then it might work.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
console.log("Server response "+ response.data);
```

instead of

```
console.log("Server response "+response.ack);
```

Comment: yeah! you get all the response in response.data then you can go further as per your object. Bdw! you can always use console.log(response.data) to check what you are actually getting in your console. Mark it as answer if you feel that it has solved your problem.